# Elastic dump from 8.9 to 2.3 throwing errors

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

When I ran the below command

```
C:\Users\ASDF>elasticdump --input=http://username:pwd@domainname/indexnameone/ --output=http://username:pwd@domainnameone/indexnametwo   --type=data
```

The error is

```
BAD_REQUEST: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"action_request_validation_exception","reason":"Validation Failed: 1: type is missing;2: type is missing;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The document types were removed in the 5.x-7.x timeframe. So you are trying to index from the version of elasticearch that doesn't support types into the version where types are mandatory. Try specifying type on your target index:

```
elasticdump --input=http://username:pwd@domainname/indexnameone/ --output=http://username:pwd@domainnameone/indexnametwo/typenametwo --type=data
```

Comment: But in terms of transfer speed, it's very slow for 105MB took 2 and half hours when I ran it on my machine.

Comment: It should be slow because it basically loads the data from a new modern version of elasticsearch and re-indexes them into 7 years old, buggy, dangerous with several actively exploited vulnerability that nobody should even attempt to run in 2023 version of elasticsearch. I am not sure why it is THAT slow though, should take a look at stats during the transfer.